# Entity Manager EJB query could not locate named parameter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, ejb

`enter code here`Hi I'm using Entity manager(EJB) which internally depends on hibernate to get Object.

My query is ........

```
TypedQuery<FraudDetectionInfoEntity> queryKount = em_oltp.createQuery("SELECT o FROM FraudDetectionInfoEntity o WHERE o.order.orderId=:orderId",FraudDetectionInfoEntity.class);
query.setParameter("orderId", orderEntity.getOrderId());
FraudDetectionInfoEntity infoEntity=queryKount.getSingleResult();
```

I'm getting folowing error If I run that query.

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [orderId]
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [orderId]
12:46:58,639 ERROR [com.vip.enterprise.admin.web.controller.OrderPlacementController] (http-/127.0.0.1:8084-6) error com.vip.enterprise.service.exception.ServiceException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [orderId]
12:47:00,001 ERROR [com.vip.enterprise.service.jobs.ReplenishmentJob] (EJB default - 4) Replenish Orders JOB : Mon Jan 27 12:47:00 IST 2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok. Missing variable `query` or `queryKount`?

```
TypedQuery<FraudDetectionInfoEntity> queryKount = em_oltp.createQuery("SELECT o FROM FraudDetectionInfoEntity o WHERE o.order.orderId=:orderId",FraudDetectionInfoEntity.class);  

query.setParameter("orderId", orderEntity.getOrderId());  
                <or>
queryKount.setParameter("orderId", orderEntity.getOrderId());
```